# How to check if [request responseString] is equal to some other string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

For example [request responseString]'s value sent by my servlet to my iphone application is  "myinfo". In my iphone application, I made a string like this:

```
 NSString *str = @"myinfo";
```

then i have if else

```
 if([responseString isEqualToString:str]){
    NSLog(@"condition true");

}else{
        NSLog(@"condition false");
}
```

in console its always showing "condition false". Whats the problem? Isn't isEqualToString is write method to check if strings are equal or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the strings are completely equal (the method is case-sensitive)

Comment: Shouldn't it be [[request responseString] isEqualToString:str]? Or do you assign [request responseString] to a variable that is named responseString and just did not include it in the sample code?

Comment: yeah sorry i didn't mention i wrote this: NSString responseString = [request responseString];   and in console they both shows myinfo.

Comment: Can you also log the string length of responseString to make sure that it is 6 characters? If it is not, there could be some whitespace or other characters in the string.

Comment: yeah length is not same. responseString has length 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSString` method `isEqualToString` is the correct thing to use here. You can do a sanity check by adding a log to your method:

```
NSLog(@"responseString = %@",responseString);
NSLog(@"str = %@",str);

if([responseString isEqualToString:str]){
    NSLog(@"condition true");

}else{
    NSLog(@"condition false");
}
```

Remember that `NSString`s are Case Sensitive, so the two strings must appear exactly the same.

Comment: responseString = myinfo  and  str = myinfo . exactly same log for both

Comment: I would suggest putting some delimiters around the string in the `NSLog`s.  That way you'll be able to see leading and trailing white space. e.g. `NSLog(@"str = <%@>",str);`

Answer (score 3):

Howwever much you think your two strings are completely equal, they are not.  Believe me, if `-isEqualToString:` did not return `YES` for two equal strings, somebody would have noticed in the 20 odd years it has been part of the Cocoa API.

I suspect that one of your two strings contains some non printing characters.  You might have a line feed or a space or a tab in it.  Another possibility (one that I came across recently) is that, for certain character set encodings, you can create an `NSString` with a nul character in it.  If it's at the end, it won't show up.  Try logging the lengths of the two strings, or converting them to `NSData` objects using the UTF16 encoding and logging them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're using connectios, sometimes the data retrieved by web is weird, you should first encode the data in a string and then NSLog it to see if it has special characters.

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRetrieved encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then you can make sure if your [request responseString] is not getting special chars.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to compare strings in ios:

```
NSString *responseString = <your string>;
NSString *string2 = <your string>;

if ([responseString caseInsensitiveCompare:string2] == NSOrderedSame) {
    //strings are same
} else {
    //strings are not same
}
```

Comment: You just posted this as an answer to another post. It is better to post one answer and link to the other via comment.